# When to use `self.foo` instead of `foo` in Ruby methods

Tags: ruby, self

This is not specific for Rails - I am just using Rails as an example.

I have a model in Rails:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  def hello
    puts "Hello, #{self.name}"
  end
end
```

(Let's assume that the `Item` model (class) has a method called `name`.) When do I need to use `self.name` and when can I just use `name` (e.g., `#{name}`)?

Comment: This is a question that trips me up too.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

1. It is idiomatic to *prefer* to omit `self.` when invoking methods; it is generally never needed.
2. You ***must*** use `self.foo = xxx` when calling a setter method, instead of `foo = xxx`, so that Ruby realizes that you are not trying create a new local variable.

   - *Similarly, in the unlikely event that you have an existing local variable `do_something` with the same name as a method, you must use `self.do_something` to invoke the method, as just `do_something` will end up reading the variable.*
3. You ***cannot*** use `self.foo(...)` to call a private method; you must instead call just `foo(...)`.

Answer (score 10):

If you omit `self` Ruby will first look for local variables with that name, then for an instance method. It's not idiomatic to write `self.`. In any case, you have to write `self.something = value` on assignations.

Note that you cannot use `self` when calling private methods (no problem with protected methods):

```
class A
  def foo; self.bar; end

private

  def bar; "bar"; end
end

A.new.foo  
# private method `bar' called for #<A:0x7f49193584f0> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [this tutorial](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2007/01/22/ruby-class-tutorial/), you have no need to use *self* pointer. But i think *this* (or *self* in our case) pointers are used to resolve name conflicts. Actually, `@name` and `self.name` are the same statements (if there is no `name` method for your class). E.g.:

```
class Moo
  attr_accessor :name

  def moo(name)
    name = name # O_o which *name* should i use?
  end

  def foo(name)
    @name = name # the same as *self.name = name*
  end

  def hello
    puts self.name # the same as *puts @name*
  end
end

a = Moo.new
a.hello() # should give no output

a.moo('zaooza')
a.hello() # Hey! Why does it prints nothing?

a.foo('zaooza')
a.hello() # whoa! This one shows 'zaooza'!
```

Try running this code and you'll see =)

Comment: Also a special case: methods named `foo=` MUST be called via `self.foo=`, otherwise it defines a new variable named `foo`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Sorry, i've overlooked that and totally forgot about operators...

Comment: `@name` and `self.name` are definitely *not* the same statement. `self.name` is a method call and `@name` is an instance variable. It's just that in your example (but not in the OP's), `self.name` is a method which happens to return `@name`. In the OP's example `self.name` will get the value stored in the database and `@name` will simply be `nil`, so they're definitely not the same.

Comment: @shybovycha: Nope, that's not corrected. If there is no `name` method, `self.name` will cause a `NoMethodError`. `self.name` is always a method call. It is never a variable (though it might very well return the contents of a variable).

Comment: sepp is right. also idiomatically, I don't think I have ever seen anyone use empty parens on a method call before in ruby.